# change link file path in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know if it is possible to change the file path of a link in excel, using text in another cell. The trick here is that the source workbook is not open at the same time as the one that has the link in it, and is not located in the same folder.

ie: if once cell has a link like:

```
='C:\thanks\forthehelp\01\[eg.xlsx]worksheet'!A1
```

and I want to change the file based on text input from a cell, ie: cell A1 has some text: "02"

```
='C:\thanks\forthehelp\&A1&\[eg.xlsx]worksheet'!A1
```

to get

```
='C:\thanks\forthehelp\02\[eg.xlsx]worksheet'!A1
```

I know the above example doesn't work, but i think it illustrates what i want to do here. Any help would be really appreciated. I hope this makes sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) to implement a constucted string to the destination workbook but INDIRECT does not work on closed workbooks.

A VBA routine could replace the formula in the cell.

```
Range("A1").Formula = Replace(Range("A1").Formula, "\01\", "\02\")
```

If you opt for this sort of formula replacement, you should check to ensure that the external workbook exists in the new location with something akin to the [Dir function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278779.aspx). Using the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) with the [xlCellTypeFormulas property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) would speed up going through the cells as opposed to looping through all of the cells and determining if the [Range.HasFormula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837123.aspx) is true.